# What can cause that, sql error 17892 is present in one client computer and not in another with same user and properly whitelisted?

Tags: sql-server, client-side

Steps to reproduce:
Computer 1: whitelist IP for userA, then connect through SSMS, SQL error 17892 shows up
Computer 2: whitelist IP for userA, then connect through SSMS successfully

What could happen in a client computer to prevent from connecting to SQL Server?

Comment: Can you share the code for the login trigger?  It might have something that does work as expected.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Server instance runs on a third party server. And cannot easily have access to login triggers. Anyhow, I am able to connect from another computer using same exact credentials, that narrows the failure to Computer 1. Is there any known failure originated at the client computer that triggers error 17892?